# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'male' in 'field list' laravel 9

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

to be honest idk what's wrong here in my code but i still receive this error i see all the solution here but nothing happen , is the problem in the type="radio"? i try to change it to type="checkbox" but it still appears an error """ datatype of checkbox-> boolean

my blade file : form ->

```
<form action="{{url('reserveinfo')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            @csrf
            <!-- ********  input user data to reserve  ******** -->
                <div class="MaleFemale">
                    <div class="Male">
                        <input type="radio" name="male" id="ML">
                        <label for="ML">Male</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Female">
                        <input type="radio" name="female" id="FML">
                        <label for="FML">Female</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="FullName">
                    <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full name">
                </div>
                
                <div class="PatientEmail">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                
                <div class="TestBirthday">
                    <div class="Test">
                        <p>Test PCR</p>
                        <div>
                            <label for="TSTFILE">
                                <img src="../Resources/File.png" for="TSTFILE">
                                    Add file</label>
                            <input type="file" name="testpcr" id="TSTFILE">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="Birthday">
                        <label for="Birthday">Birthday</label>
                        <input type="date" name="date">
                    </div>

                </div>
                
                <div class="DoctopPres">
                    <p>Doctor prescription</p>
                    <div>
                        <label for="DctrPres">
                            <img src="../Resources/File.png" for="DctrPres">
                            Add file</label>
                        <input type="file" name="doctorpres" id="DctrPres">
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <!--##########  Send request ########## -->
                <div class="Reserve">
                    <a href="../HtmlFiles/Reserve-3-.html">
                        <button>Reserve</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Controllers code :

```
public function reserveinfo(Request $request){

        $data = new reserveinfo;
        $data->male=$request->Male;
        $data->female=$request->female;

        $data->fullname=$request->fullname;
        $data->email=$request->email;
        $data->birthday=$request->date;


        $test_pcr=$request->file('testpcr');
        $imagename=time().'.'.$test_pcr->getClientoriginalExtension();
        $request->testpcr->move('Text-PCR-of-users',$imagename);
        $data->$test_pcr=$imagename;

        $Doctor_prescription=$request->file('doctorpres');
        $imagename2=time().'.'.$Doctor_prescription->getClientoriginalExtension();
        $request->doctorpres->move('Doctor-prescription-of-users',$imagename2);
        $data->doctorpres=$imagename2; 





        
        if(Auth::id()){
            $data->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
        }

        $data->save();

        return redirect()->back();

    
    }
```

routes :

```
Route::get('/reserve1_view',[UserController::class,'addview']);

Route::get('/reserve2_view',[UserController::class,'addview2']);

Route::post('/reserveinfo',[UserController::class,'reserveinfo']);
```

migrations code :

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('reserve2s', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->boolean('male')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('female')->nullable();
            $table->string('fullname')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->string('test_pcr')->nullable();
            $table->string('birthday')->nullable();
            $table->string('Doctor_prescription')->nullable();
            $table->string('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('reserve2s');
    }
};
```

and get this error :

```
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'male' in 'field list
```

models code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class reserveinfo extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

""" nothing add to models """

thanks for reading this XD

Comment: when you do `dd((new reserveinfo)->getTable());` what do you get ?

Comment: Post your `reservinfo` model code.

Comment: where i didn't understand ? but the db was created but no input in it

Comment: nothing is add to it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class reserveinfo extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'reserve2s';
}
```

I recommend you read the Laravel manual about Eloquent's naming convention.

[Eloquent Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

In your second error you are using the value of the variable `$test_pcr` as the attribute name. Just remove the `$`.

```php
// Change this
$data->$test_pcr=$imagename;
// to
$data->test_pcr=$imagename;

// Change this
$data->doctorpres=$imagename2;
// to
$data->Doctor_prescription=$imagename2;
```

Remembering that you should read about Eloquent to understand how this integration works with the model and the database table.

Comment: thank u so much it works the input image was saved in the folder i created , but there is no data in my data base  and this error __>>SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpD7B8.tmp' in 'field list  __<< can u help please ?

Comment: Replace `$request->testpcr->move('Text-PCR-of-users',$imagename);` with `$test_pcr->move('Text-PCR-of-users',$imagename);` and  `$request->doctorpres->move('Doctor-prescription-of-users',$imagename2);` with `$Doctor_prescription->->move('Doctor-prescription-of-users',$imagename2);` assuming `Text-PCR-of-users` and `Doctor-prescription-of-users` are valid paths to store the uploaded files.

Comment: I edited my answer with the solution to this problem.